# Why can't I center a group?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Alright, so obviously if I want to center a certain text I use the enviroment function as followed:

> \begin{center} text to be influenced \end{center}

But why can't I instead use the group function to center a certain text like this:

> \bgroup \centering text to be influenced \egroup

or

> {\centering text to be influenced}

both of the group examples just produce regular, non centered text for some reason. If I leave the \bgroup \egroup // the {} and just do as followed
\centering text to be influenced

obviously all the text that follows after \centering gets centered up until I use a different arrangment command. I just don't understand why it's doing nothing if I put the \centering in a group.

Any Help?

PS I'm an absolute noob as you might see.

Comment: add a `\par` before the closing brace/`\egroup`.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph is processed when a `\par` (or a blank line) is found.

So in your second and third example, the `\centering` command has no effect when you exit the group, and the paragraph (when finished) will be processed with whatever configuration you had before.

So you should use `{\centering text to be centered \par}` or

```
\bgroup 
\centering
Text to be centered

\egroup
```

(notice the blank line).

The `center` environment add a `\par` before the end (and additional space, too, normally).