# Why can't I process \centering with \par when there is no group?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

This is a follow up in my previous question, [Why can't I center a group?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451760/why-cant-i-center-a-group)

I asked why I can't use \centering to center a group. I got an answer saying that a paragraph is processed when a \par (or a blank line) is found. And only if I leave a blank line / the \par command BEFORE closing the group it will process the \centering command.

Alright that worked. BUT, following that explanation I was thinking if I do something like

> \centering this is a text
>
> this is another text

or

> \centering this is a text \par this is another text

"this is another text" should not be centered, as the paragraph "this is a text" ends with the empty line / the \par.

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the `\par` does not extinguish the effet of `\centering`, which mainly sets `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` to infinitely stretchable glue so that text is centered.

Comment: Alright, but why does the same thing not happen when I put the hole thing in a group? I mean that outs me back to my previous question, or more specifically why does the \centering not take place without the \par in a group?

Comment: During paragraph "parsing" TeX accumulates "horizontal" material (characters, glues, penalties, ...) until it encounters `\par` (or a blank line which creates a `\par` token not written by user). Only then does it apply its algorithms to split the "horizontal" material into a paragraph composed of lines.

Answer (score 3):

`\centering` is a declaration and therefore its scope extends “forever”, but “forever” means “until the group where the declaration is issued ends”.

In your case `\centering` is issued at the top level, so its scope extends up to the end of the document, unless countermanded by a similar declaration such as `\raggedright` or `\raggedleft`. There is *no* `\uncentering` declaration, so grouping is necessary.

However, by rule of TeX, a paragraph is set with the values of some relevant parameters active at the point `\par` is executed.

Thus, as in your previous question,

```
{\centering This text will not be centered}

And neither this one
```

will typeset two normally justified paragraphs, because the `\par` implied by the blank line acts when the scope of `\centering` has ended, restoring the paragraphing parameters to the values they had before the `{`.

If you want centered text followed by justified text, you need to do *two* paragraphs:

```
{\centering This text will be centered\par}
\noindent And this text will start from the left margin.
```

However, good typography dictates that the centered part is separated by the justified one:

```
\begin{center}
This text will be centered
\end{center}
And this text will start from the left margin.
```

#### Examples

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Bad}

{\centering This text will not be centered}

And neither this one

\section{Ugly}

{\centering This text will be centered\par}
\noindent And this text will start from the left margin.

\section{Good}

\begin{center}
This text will be centered
\end{center}
And this text will start from the left margin.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> And only if I leave a blank line / the \par command BEFORE closing the
>   group it will process the \centering command.

This is misleading. The `\centering` has an immediate effect on some parameters. However, only the values of those parameters in place *at the time* the paragraph builder is triggered by a `\par` (either explicit or implicit from a blank line) will influence the paragraph shape.

So the `\centering` command is "processed" immediately but may have nil effect if a group closes before the next `\par` or another command again resets the paragraph parameters (leftskip, rightskip mainly).

Notice that the same applies to the `\baselineskip` for example.

Perhaps, don't use LaTeX2e "command" terminology which is misleading. TeX is a macro-expansion language and `\centering` is a macro.

```
$ latexdef centering

\centering:
macro:->\let \\\@centercr \rightskip \@flushglue \leftskip \@flushglue \parindent \z@ \parfillskip \z@skip
```

As we see in the above it does some assignments. These assignments are canceled if a group closes. If that happens before the `\par`,  the effet on the paragraph builder will be nil.