# Why does centering not center?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I'm trying to get an image centered within an itemize list preferably without the use of the center environment (since this induces a call of \item which I otherwise redefine so that pages are ended at the end of every item). But it seems as though my centering is not centering.

The minimal example below demonstrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item Item text 
 \begin{center}
 I'm centered, which is nice.
 \end{center}

\item Item text 

 {\centering Why am I not centered?}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centering` is only processed (only takes effect) at the end of a paragraph.  You closed the group (right brace) without a paragraph ending.  Thus, add `\par` prior to right brace: `{\centering Why am I not centered?\par}`

Comment: Like @StevenB.Segletes said. You could add an explicit paragraph break: `{\centering I'm centered!\par}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I would take it as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/2975. It is used for many similar questions already.

Comment: Also related: [Why can't I center a group?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451760/2975)

Comment: @MartinScharrer I think the solution is a duplicate. I found both questions but I obviously didn't look long enough. Thing is, I know why I want centering and not center.

Comment: @Geoff: Ok, not a problem. closing at duplicate.